# How get positive and negative number after 1 and 2 digit in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the problem. I have 100 digits from 1 to 100 and each time I want a positive and negative number after 1 and 2 digit gap.

Here is the condition.

I want sequence like this

```
(+)1
(-)2
(+)3
(+)4
(-)5
(+)6
(-)7
(+)8
(+)9
(-)10
(+)11
(-)12
(+)13
(+)14
(-)15
(+)16
(-)17
(+)18
(+)19 
(-)20 and so on 100
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply, looking for string like this +1,-2,+3 and so on

Comment: Why is JavaScript tagged?

Comment: because I'm using javascript and PHP in my project.

Comment: But the question is PHP? Then JavaScript should not be tagged. Tags are what you want the answer to be in now what you use, know, eat etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one more solution to get these sequence using php.

```
$pattern=array(1,-1,1,1,-1);
$j=0;
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){

    IF(isset($pattern[$j])){
        echo $pattern[$j].'<br>';
    }
    $j++;
    if($i%5==0){
        $j=0;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1
-1
1
1
-1
1
-1
1
1
-1
```

Comment: But this is not the pattern you requested in question. You asked for 1-100.

Answer (score 0):

You can array_chunk it at 5 (that is one loop as I see it) and echo the parts with + and -.

I added if isset because it doesn't end correctly, there will be notices without it.

If you need a string you can just replace the echo with `$str .=`

```
$arr = range(1,100);

Foreach(array_chunk($arr,5) as $items){
    If(isset($items[0])) Echo "+" . $items[0] . "\n";
    If(isset($items[1])) Echo "-" . $items[1] . "\n";
    If(isset($items[2])) Echo "+" . $items[2] . "\n";
    If(isset($items[3])) Echo "+" . $items[3] . "\n";
    If(isset($items[4])) Echo "-" . $items[4] . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/OKhbM

Comment: I think the loop is 5 long (+/-/+/+/-)

Comment: Thank you so much @Andreas. You save my day :)